# Add text annotations to each data point in Holoviews plot

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

In Bokeh I am able to add a text annotation to each point in my plot programmatically by using `LabelSet`. Below I give an example for a simple bar plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Make some data
dat = \
(pd.DataFrame({'team':['a','b','c'], 'n_people':[10,5,12]})
    .assign(n_people_percent = lambda x: (x['n_people']/np.sum(x['n_people'])*100)
        .round(1).astype('string') + '%')
)

dat
```

[image]

```
# Bar plot with text annotations for every bar
from bkcharts import show, Bar
from bkcharts.attributes import CatAttr
from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, LabelSet)

source_labs = ColumnDataSource(data = dat)
p = Bar(data = dat, label = CatAttr(columns = 'team'), values = 'n_people')
labels = LabelSet(x = 'team', y = 'n_people',
    text = 'n_people_percent', source = source_labs)
p.add_layout(labels)
show(p)
```

[image]

However I am not sure how to achieve the same thing with Holoviews. I can make the same bar plot without the annotations very easily:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

p = hv.Bars(dat, kdims=['team'], vdims=['n_people'])
p
```

[image]

I can add a single text label adding an Overlay with the `hv.Text` element

```
p * hv.Text('a', 11, '37.0%')
```

[image]

But I have no idea how I can label each bar without explicitly calling `hv.Text` separately for every data point (bar). The problem seems to be that `hv.Text` does not accept a `data` argument like other elements e.g. `hv.Bars`, instead just `x` and `y` coordinates. My intuition would be that I should be able to do something like

```
p * hv.Text(dat, kdims=['team'], vdims=['n_people_percent'])
```

Any help with this appreciated!

Comment: We haven't yet added a vectorized Text Element but it would be fairly straightforward to do so. There is some discussion about this [here](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues/1837) including a link to an implementation for such an Element. For now you can simply create an Overlay of multiple regular Text Elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this [commit](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/pull/2352) adds vectorized labels to `hv.Labels`, so try:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

p = hv.Bars(dat, kdims=['team'], vdims=['n_people'])
p * hv.Labels(dat, kdims=['team', 'n_people'], vdims=['n_people_percent'])
```