# Adding values to grouped bar chart in hvplot

Tags: holoviews, pyviz, hvplot

I'm trying to add labels to a **grouped hvplot barchart**.

My example dataframe has the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas
hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B'],
                   'B' : [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                   'C' : list((range(20,26)))

                  })
```

The bar chart is created with the following code:

```
bar = df.hvplot.bar(x='B', y='C', by='A')
bar
```

[hvplot bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hqQK.png)

I tried to add labels according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223037/add-text-annotations-to-each-data-point-in-holoviews-plot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900736/adding-value-labels-to-hvplot-bar) SO questions:

```
labels = hv.Labels(data=df, kdims=['B','A'],vdims='C')
labels
```

But an overlay of both plots

```
bar * labels
```

results in an error, though the dimensions seem to be the same for me.

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

:Overlay
   .Bars.I   :Bars   [B,A]   (C)
   .Labels.I :Labels   [B,A]   (C)
```

Any hint to the solution is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible for normal bar charts, but unfortunately this is not possible yet for grouped barcharts: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/pull/3385

You could create separate bar charts per category in col A and then add labels, but you won't have a grouped bar chart then:

```py
def barplot_and_labels_category(category):
    df_subset = df[df.A == category]

    plot = df_subset.hvplot.bar(x='B', y='C', ylim=(0, 30))

    labels = hv.Labels(
        df_subset, 
        kdims=['B', 'C'], 
        vdims='C',
    ).opts(text_color='black', text_font_size='20pt')

    return plot * labels
```

```
(barplot_and_labels_category('A') + barplot_and_labels_category('B')).cols(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Sander for pointing that out!
Hopefully it will be possible for bar charts soon, as this feature is highly requested in my organization.